# Chartjs 2.0 Modify Y-Axis Values

Tags: chart.js

I have a line chart working fine using chartjs 2.0, but I would like to modify the numeric values of the y-axis. For instance divide the values by 100. Is it possible?

Comment: Please show us the code as well, it will make it easier to give a concrete suggestion, thanks!

Comment: @plamut No problem. Let me explain more. I have data (seconds) stored in a db that i want to output in the format hh:mm:ss. It is grouped by a second datetime column grouping multiple points into month. So essentially I have November-15 with data points of say 00:58:12 and 115:32:19. I find if the data is in the format of hh:mm:ss the chart wont render so am wondering if i output the data in second format if i can modify the y-axis values so they are in the format I am after. Code exert [link](http://pastebin.com/YNvwWn0D), I have changed the data from php echo's to hard coded whole numbers.